# using hound code search engine with private git repository accessible via ssh?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to set up [hound](https://github.com/etsy/hound#quick-start-guide) to search our internal repositories. These repositories are accessible via ssh urls that look like the ones below:

```
ssh://git.my_company.com/project/MyProjectA
ssh://git.my_company.com/project/MyProjectB
```

In the hound [quick start manual](https://github.com/etsy/hound#quick-start-guide) I read:

**Use SSH style URLs in the config: "url" : "git@github.com:foo/bar.git". As long as you have your SSH keys set up on the box where Hound is running this will work.**

So I added the following to my config.json file:

```
 "MyProjectA" : {
     "url" : "my_user@git.my_company.com/pkg/MyProjectA"
 }
```

But I don't feel it is quite right as in the quick start example the url points to a **bar.git** file, but I don't have a parallel **MyProjectA.git** file, so in fact I'm pointing to the root dir of my repository, under which one can find a .git directory.

And, as expected, it errors:

2017/01/25 15:05:00 Failed to clone my_user@git.my_company.com/pkg/MyProjectA, see output below
fatal: repository 'my_user@git.my_company.com/pkg/MyProjectA' does not exist

Anyone has a clue if it is possible to get this working and how? I can clone everything locally, but that means that the search engine doesn't pick up changes, which is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

The following pretty obvious solution works...

```
"MyProjectA" : {
    "url" : "git.my_company.com/pkg/MyProjectA"
}
```